# Referencing elements in parsed json

Tags: python, json

I am relatively new to python and coding in general so I really need help in this. This is my code and I will tell you what I am trying, and failing, to reference afterwards:

```
>>> import json
>>> import urllib2
>>> j = urllib2.urlopen('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Dublin+Ireland&destinations=Cork+Ireland|Limerick+Ireland|Galway+Ireland|&mode=driving&sensor=false')
>>> js = json.load(j)
>>> ourResult = js['rows'][0]['elements']
>>> for rs in ourResult:
>>> print rs['distance']
{u'text': u'255 km', u'value': 255493}
{u'text': u'197 km', u'value': 196553}
{u'text': u'208 km', u'value': 208373}
```

I am trying to reference just the distance value (ie. the 'text' value) but all I can do is reference the letters. I have tried:

```
>>> x = rs['distance']
>>> z = [y[0] for y in x]
>>> print z
[u't', u'v']
```

All that I can reference is the letters but never the numbers.
I don't know what else to try so any help at all would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 3):

You want to access the value within the dictionary, I.E.:

```
for rs in ourResult:
    print(rs['distance']['text'])
```

Your problem is that `y in dictionary` lists the keys of a dictionary, not that values. In your last list comprehension, you are printing the 0-index item (first letter) of each key.

Just for kicks, try copying and running this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dictionary = OrderedDict([("list", "value 0"), ("the", "value 1"), ("keys", "value 2")])

print("key in dictionary:")
for key in dictionary:
    print(key)

print("value in dictionary.values():")
for value in dictionary.values():
    print(value)

print("key, value in dictionary.items():")
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print(key, value)
```

`OrderedDict`s act like normal dictionaries, but also keep track of the order of their `key:value` pairs. I used one here so that the example output would be oredered, but you can think if it as just another dictionary as far as `.values`, `.keys`, and `.items` are concerned.